# Mistake in loop in Caesar Cipher, only last letter gets replaced. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am a completely newbie to Python, so I apologize if I made any silly mistakes.
As said in the title, only the last letter is replaced when I run my code.
For example, if I type "meet", the result will be "meeW" instead of "PHHW".
We are suppose to use the ascii value, so I cannot use uppercase.

```
def CaesarCipher(po):
    "Encrypt a string"
    x=0
    while (x < len(po)):
        if ord(po[x])<120:
            to = chr(ord(po[x])-29)
            new = po.replace(po[x], to)
        else:
            to = chr(ord(po[x])-55)
            new = po.replace(po[x], to)
        x=x+1

    print (new)

def main():
    po = input("Enter a string: ")
    CaesarCipher(po)

main()
```

I think the problem is with the loop update. Can anyone help me identify the mistake in the loop? Thanks!

P.S. This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, so I am sorry if I made any mistakes in the way I should present my question.

Comment: new = po.replace(po[x], to) <-- po isn't changed so new is equal to your last iteration attribution

Comment: Why does using ascii mean you cant use uppercase?

Comment: Basically we are supposed to use ascii value only, but not str.upper().

Answer (score 0):

You should append to `new` instead of assigning it a new value each time it iterates.

Replace `new = po.replace(po[x], to)` with `new += to`

Also, I don't see where you declared `new`, so at the start of `CaesarCipher` you should add `new = ''` or `global new` if you want to use a global variable for `new`

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved my problem by defining "new" as equal to "po".
Thanks to everyone for telling me to correct the "new" variable!

```
def CaesarCipher(po):
    "Encrypt a string"
    x=0
    while (x < len(po)):
        if 97<=ord(po[x])<120:
            to = chr(ord(po[x])-29)
            new = po.replace(po[x], to)
            po = new
        elif 120<=ord(po[x])<=122:
            to = chr(ord(po[x])-55)
            new = po.replace(po[x], to)
            po = new
        x=x+1

    print (new)

def main():
    po = input("Enter a string: ")
    CaesarCipher(po)

main()
```